# javascript checking for current url not working

Tags: javascript

I want to check if my current page URL is ending with this `/something` and if is ending with that, do something.

So, I've tried this:

```
if('http://'+location.hostname+location.pathname+'/something') {
  //do something;
}
```

here it validates every time even if I'm not on that specific URL .

Then, I've tried this:

```
if(location.pathname === "/something") {
  // Do Something
}
```

Here, I'm getting `Undefined` inside the console.

I understand that this means that I have an error in my code somewhere but I don't know where this error might be ?

How can I check where the error occurs ?

**LATER UPDATE:** 
I've tried every answer in the console and for each one I'm getting `Undefined`
This is how my URL is looking `website.com/parent/child/something`.
Inside the `if` statement I'm just trying to hide and element which exists on the page like this: `jQuery(".class").hide();`
This is so frustrating, It's definetly something wrong with the code.

Comment: In the first case, you are just building a non-emtpy string, and every non-empty string evaluates to `true`. The second example looks better, if you want to test whether the whole pathname is `/something`. I don't know where you could get the `undefined` from, it looks like you are not even logging anything to the console.

Comment: inside the `if` statement I'm just trying to hide an element which exists on the page. I've updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

Use`window.location.href` to get the current URL, or `window.location.pathname` to get just the path

```
if(window.location.pathname=="yourvalue")
```

Comment: Tried it, and I'm getting the same Undefined. I've updated my question with how the URL looking and what I'm writing inside the if statement

Answer (score 0):

That's checks a last element of a url path.

```
if (window.location.pathname.split('/').pop() === "something") {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Tried it, and I'm getting the same `Undefined`. I've updated my question with how the URL looking and what I'm writing inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/first/second/something";
var url_ending = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"), url.length);
if(url_ending == "something"){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url = window.location.href;
 var url_ending = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"), url.length);
 if(url_ending == "something")
 {
     // Do something
 }
 else
 {
     //Do other things 
 }

 hope this will help.
```

Comment: Tried it, and I'm getting the same Undefined. I've updated my question with how the URL looking and what I'm writing inside the if statement